I want to create a plugin that will re-write old posts using google studio api
I have several old post which i want to revamp but rewriting them automatically using a plugin. i have formulated  the code of the plugin but is not working well. te posts are not getting re-written. below is my code:
<?php

/**

 * Plugin Name: Article Rewriter

 * Description: A plugin to rewrite old posts of the "job" post type and show 

progress, including detailed content changes, using AI Studio API.

 * Version: 1.0

 * Author: Your Name

 */

// Exit if accessed directly

if (!defined('ABSPATH')) {

    exit;
}

// Add a menu page in the admin panel

add_action('admin_menu', 'article_rewriter_menu');

function article_rewriter_menu() {

    add_menu_page(

        'Article Rewriter',

        'Article Rewriter',

        'manage_options',

        'article_rewriter',

        'article_rewriter_page',

        'dashicons-edit',

        20

    );

}


// Display the plugin page

function article_rewriter_page() {

    ?>

    <div class="wrap">

        <h1>Article Rewriter</h1>

        <p>This tool will rewrite old posts of the "job" post type using AI Studio 
API.</p>


        <form method="post">

            <input type="submit" name="start_rewrite" class="button button-primary" 
value="Start Rewriting Jobs">

            <input type="submit" name="stop_rewrite" class="button button-secondary" value="Stop Rewriting Jobs">

            <input type="submit" name="restart_rewrite" class="button button-secondary" value="Restart Rewriting Jobs">

        </form>

        <div id="progress-bar-container" style="margin-top: 20px; width: 100%; 
background-color: #f3f3f3; height: 20px; border-radius: 5px; overflow: hidden;">

            <div id="progress-bar" style="width: 0%; height: 100%; background-color: green;"></div>

        </div>

        <div id="progress-status" style="margin-top: 10px;"></div>


        <div id="processed-posts" style="margin-top: 20px;">

            <h3>Processed Posts:</h3>

            <ul id="post-list"></ul>

        </div>


        <div id="all-processed-posts" style="margin-top: 30px;">

            <h3>Posts That Have Been Processed</h3>

            <table class="widefat fixed" cellspacing="0">

                <thead>

                    <tr>

                        <th scope="col" class="manage-column">Post ID</th>

                        <th scope="col" class="manage-column">Title</th>

                        <th scope="col" class="manage-column">Status</th>

                        <th scope="col" class="manage-column">Date</th>

                    </tr>

                </thead>

                <tbody>

                    <?php article_rewriter_list_processed_jobs(); ?>

                </tbody>

            </table>

        </div>

    </div>

    <?php


    // Handle the post request to start, stop, or restart the rewriting process

    if (isset($_POST['start_rewrite'])) {

        article_rewriter_start();

    } elseif (isset($_POST['stop_rewrite'])) {

        article_rewriter_stop();

    } elseif (isset($_POST['restart_rewrite'])) {

        article_rewriter_restart();

    }


    // Display current progress status

    article_rewriter_display_status();

}


// Start the rewriting process

function article_rewriter_start() {

    // Initialize/reset the progress and processed posts

    set_transient('article_rewriter_status', ['start' => 0, 'is_running' => true, 'batch_size' => 10]);

    set_transient('article_rewritten_posts', []); // Track processed posts
    article_rewriter_process_batch(0);

}

// Stop the rewriting process

function article_rewriter_stop() {

    // Update status to stopped

    set_transient('article_rewriter_status', ['is_running' => false]);

    echo "<script>alert('Rewriting process has been stopped.');</script>";

}


// Restart the rewriting process

function article_rewriter_restart() {

    // Reset progress and processed posts, and restart from the beginning

    delete_transient('article_rewriter_status');

    delete_transient('article_rewritten_posts');

    article_rewriter_start();

}


// Display the current status of the rewriting process

function article_rewriter_display_status() {

    $status = get_transient('article_rewriter_status');


    if ($status && $status['is_running']) {

        // Show progress bar and status

        $start = $status['start'];

        echo "<script>document.getElementById('progress-status').innerHTML = 'Rewriting job posts... " . $start . " of 100';</script>";

    } else {

        echo "<script>document.getElementById('progress-status').innerHTML = 'Process has stopped or not started yet.';</script>";

    }

}


// Process the job posts in batches

function article_rewriter_process_batch($start = 0, $batch_size = 10) {

    // Query for job posts with pagination (batching)

    $args = array(

        'post_type' => 'job',

        'posts_per_page' => $batch_size,

        'post_status' => 'publish',

        'offset' => $start,  // Start from the current batch

    );


    $jobs = new WP_Query($args);

    $total_posts = $jobs->found_posts;


    // If there are posts to update

    if ($jobs->have_posts()) {

        $updated_posts = [];


        foreach ($jobs->posts as $post) {

            // Original content of the post

            $original_content = $post->post_content;


            // Call the AI API to rewrite the content

            $new_content = call_ai_rewrite_api($original_content);


            // Use the AI API to update the post content

            if (!empty($new_content) && $new_content !== $original_content) {

                // Example rewrite logic: Modify the post title and content

                $new_title = $post->post_title . ' - Updated';


                // Save original title and content for tracking changes

                $original_title = $post->post_title;


                // Update the post with the new rewritten content

                wp_update_post(array(

                    'ID' => $post->ID,

                    'post_title' => $new_title,

                    'post_content' => $new_content

                ));


                // Track the changes (Title and Content)

                $updated_posts[] = [

                    'ID' => $post->ID,

                    'original_title' => $original_title,

                    'new_title' => $new_title,

                    'original_content' => $original_content,

                    'new_content' => $new_content,

                    'link' => get_permalink($post->ID), // Include the post's link

                    'content_changes' => get_content_changes($original_content, 
$new_content)

                ];


                // Store the processed post ID in transient

                $processed_posts = get_transient('article_rewritten_posts');

                $processed_posts[] = $post->ID;

                set_transient('article_rewritten_posts', $processed_posts);

            }

        }


        // Update progress and save the batch number

        $progress = ($start + $batch_size) / $total_posts * 100;

        $next_start = $start + $batch_size;


        // Save the status (progress and start)

        set_transient('article_rewriter_status', ['start' => $next_start,
 'is_running' => true, 'batch_size' => 10]);


        // Output the progress bar and status via JavaScript

        echo "<script>


                document.getElementById('progress-bar').style.width = '" . $progress 
. "%';

                document.getElementById('progress-status').innerHTML = 'Rewriting job posts... " . ($start + $batch_size) . " of $total_posts';

              </script>";


        // Flush output and wait for the next batch

        flush();

        ob_flush();

        // Display the updated posts with changes

        echo "<script>";

        $post_list_html = '';

        foreach ($updated_posts as $updated_post) {

            $post_list_html .= '<li>';

            $post_list_html .= 'Post ID: ' . $updated_post['ID'] . ' - ';

            $post_list_html .= 'Title: <b>' . $updated_post['original_title'] . '</b>
 → <i>' . $updated_post['new_title'] . '</i><br>';

            $post_list_html .= 'Content Changes: <br>';

            $post_list_html .= 'Original: <i>' . 
substr($updated_post['original_content'], 0, 100) . '...</i><br>';

            $post_list_html .= 'Rewritten: <i>' . 
substr($updated_post['new_content'], 0, 100) . '...</i><br>';

            $post_list_html .= 'Link: <a href="' . $updated_post['link'] . '" 
target="_blank">View Post</a>';

            $post_list_html .= '</li>';

        }

        echo "document.getElementById('post-list').innerHTML = '" . addslashes($post_list_html) . "';";

        echo "</script>";


        // If we haven't processed all posts, schedule the next batch

        if (($start + $batch_size) < $total_posts) {

            // Redirect to trigger the next batch

            echo "<script>setTimeout(function() { location.href = '" . admin_url('admin.php?page=article_rewriter') . "&start=" . $next_start . "'; }, 

1000);</script>";

        } else {

            // Completed all posts

            echo "<p>Rewriting process completed for all posts!</p>";

        }

    } else {

        // No more posts to rewrite

        echo "<p>No job posts found to rewrite.</p>";

    }

}


// Function to call the AI Studio API for rewriting content

function call_ai_rewrite_api($text) {

    // Define the API endpoint and your API key (you can replace these with actual values)

    $api_url = 'https://aistudio.google.com/app/apikey'; // Replace with actual endpoint if different
    

    // Your actual API key

    $api_key = 'AxxxxxxxxxxA';  // Your API key


    // Prepare data for API request

    $data = [

        'text' => $text,

        'apikey' => $api_key  // Send the API key along with the text to the AI service

    ];


    // Use WordPress HTTP API to make the POST request

    $response = wp_remote_post($api_url, [

        'method'    => 'POST',

        'body'      => json_encode($data),

        'headers'   => [

            'Content-Type'  => 'application/json'

        ]

    ]);


    // Check if the request was successful

    if (is_wp_error($response)) {


        return '';  // Return an empty string if there was an error

    }

    // Parse the response

    $body = wp_remote_retrieve_body($response);

    $data = json_decode($body, true);


    // Return the rewritten text from the API response

    if (isset($data['rewritten_text'])) {

        return $data['rewritten_text'];  // Return the rewritten content

    }


    // In case of failure, return the original text

    return $text;  // Return original content if the API does not return a rewritten version

}

// List processed posts in the admin page

function article_rewriter_list_processed_jobs() {

    $processed_posts = get_transient('article_rewritten_posts');


    if (empty($processed_posts)) {

        echo "<tr><td colspan='4'>No posts have been processed yet.</td></tr>";

    } else {

        foreach ($processed_posts as $post_id) {

            $post = get_post($post_id);

            echo "<tr>

                    <td>" . $post->ID . "</td>

                    <td>" . $post->post_title . "</td>

                    <td>Rewritten</td>

                    <td>" . $post->post_date . "</td>

                </tr>";

        }

    }

}

// Function to get content changes (example: a simple diff)

function get_content_changes($original_content, $new_content) {

    // Here, you could implement a proper diffing mechanism or logic

    // For simplicity, we'll show the text difference (basic example)

    return [

        'Original: ' . substr($original_content, 0, 100),  // Show the first 100 characters

        'Rewritten: ' . substr($new_content, 0, 100)

    ];

}

?>

i tried to make the given code above
